# Touchscreen support

Tags: raspbian, touchscreen

I just got a new 10" screen with capacative touch from chalk-elec and it has been working fine. The only problem I have is when I try to use the touchscreen it creates ghost touches and jumps and sometimes just freezes. On windows it happens too but it goes to the corner as well. Anybody got this figured out properly? I have tried re calibrating but it doesn't seem to do much. And I also tried creating a `50-ntrig.conf` in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/`. Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: Your definition of working fine differs from the traditional one.  Have you complained to the vendor?

Comment: Yes I have but they haven't responded yet.